# Yii2 ActiveForm: display Ajax validation response at the top of the form or in errorSummary()

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, yii2

I'm using ActiveForm and I would need to display the validation errors not close to the input fields but rather at the top of the form.

As shown in the sample code below, setting `errorOptions` I avoid to display the error message in the default position.

Ajax validation is working but the `$form->errorSummary($model)` doesn't show any message, even if [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9700#issuecomment-141105916) it seems like it should and in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#errorSummary()-detail) I could not find a clear answer.

Also, adding `Html::error($model, 'username')` does not help with Ajax validation.

```php
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'test-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
    ]) 
?>

<?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>
<?= Html::error($model, 'username') ?>

<div class="form-row"> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'username', ['errorOptions' => ['tag' => false]])->textInput()->label("Username") ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

In Yii1.1 the validation errors can be displayed in a more flexible way, since you could define `label`, `input` and `error` individually. Something like this:

```php
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
```

In that case you can simply move `$form->error($model,'username');` anywhere within the form.

How is it possible to obtain the same results with Yii2 without using the [Javascript API](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-form-javascript)?

- Display the Ajax validation errors for individual input at the top of the form.
- Display the Ajax validation errors with `errorSummary()`

***Edit***

I forgot to mention that I'm using Bootstrap4 through the extension [yii2-bootstrap4](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4). Part of the problems I'm having with the error display may be related to [this bug](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4/issues/128).

Considering the answer from @serghei-leonenco I add here some complete minimal code to replicate the problem.

**Model**

```php
namespace frontend\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
class AjaxForm extends \yii\base\Model
{
    public $demo;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // define validation rules here
            [['demo'], 'required'],
            [['demo'], 'string', 'length' => [2, 4]],

        ];
    }
}
```

**View**

```php
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'test-form',
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-horizontal'],
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'enableClientValidation' => false,]) ?>

        <div class="form-row"> 
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <?php echo $form->field($model, 'demo', ['template' => '{error}']); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row"> 
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'demo')->textInput()->label("Demo") ?>
                <?php echo $form->field($model, 'demo', ['template' => '{error}']); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Submit 1', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','name' => 'submit1']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```php
public function actionTestajax()
{
    $model = new AjaxForm();

    // Ajax validation
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $ret = ActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::info("Ajax validation: " . json_encode($ret));
        return $ret;
    }    

    // form submit
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if($model->validate()){
            // valid data received in $model
            //var_dump($model);
            return $this->render('testajax_submit', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('testajax', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('testajax', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

Out of the three `<div class="invalid-feedback">Demo cannot be blank.</div>`, only one is shown, the other two maintain the style `.invalid-feedback {display: none;}`.

The `$form->errorSummary($model)`:

after the validation is performed, returns this:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <p>Please fix the following errors:</p>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

after the form is submitted, returns this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="">
    <p>Please fix the following errors:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Demo cannot be blank.</li>
        <li>Demo cannot be blank.</li>
        <li>Demo cannot be blank.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did tested out `$form->errorSummary();` and it does shows the desired output, but in the form of:

> Please fix the following errors:
>
> Please enter Username.

Like an option, you can do it this way:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'id' => 'test-form',
      'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
      'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
      'enableClientValidation' => true,
]); ?>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <div class="error-block text-center">
          <?php
              $error = $form->field($model, 'username');
              $error->template = '{error}';
              echo $error;
          ?>
      </div>
      <?php
          $username = $form->field($model, 'username');
          $username->template = "{input}";
          echo $username->textInput(['autofocus' => true]);
      ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

The output will be right above the form field will be the response with:

> Please enter Username

Comment: I like the suggestion, it can be written in a more compact way: `echo $form->field($model, 'username', ['template' => '{error}']);`.
I still have some visualization problem that I cannot explain. `$form->errorSummary();` doesn't show errors (I can see in the dev-console that is not populated).
Also, the proposed solution works but is not displayed to me. I can see in the style `.invalid-feedback {display: none;}` and I don't understand why.